# Clicked "Accept Yours" during git pull instead of "Accept Theirs"

Tags: git, android-studio

During the `git pull` I accidentally clicked "Accept Yours" on 1 file, instead to click on "Accept Theirs". So I now have my version of that file, instead of version committed to the repository.

How can I undo this and fetch their version of this file? Is `git chechout <file name>` the right way to go?

PS. I pulled form repo via Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pull again and also use git reset to move the head to where you want to be.

Read up on both `git reset, git reflog`

```
git reset number —soft (the least distractive of all)
    git reset number --hard
    git reflog
```

The number is the commit number. For example on a terminal do the following:

```
git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all
```

to see your log.

Answer (score 0):

**Select** the list of changes it's showing in “**Version Control**” view in the bottom of Android Studio.

Right-click on the selection and select “**Revert**” option.

Now it don't show any local changes(i.e working directory clean).

Then pull again and select “**Accept Theirs**”.